# not able to fetch data from linked table using automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I do have a model.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Text;

namespace OnlineLearning.Model
{
    public class SessionDetail
            : BaseEntity
    {
        public Guid SchoolId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("SchoolId")]
        public School School { get; set; }
        public String SessionTitle { get; set; }
        public String SessionDesc { get; set; }
        public Guid ClassId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClassId")]
        public ClassDetail ClassDetail { get; set; }
        public Guid TeacherId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("TeacherId")]
        public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
        public DateTime ScheduledDate { set; get; }
        public string StartingTime { get; set; }
        public string EndingTime { get; set; }
        public Guid? SessionStatusId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And view model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace OnlineLearning.DTO.ViewModel
{
  public class SessionViewModel
  {
    public String SessionTitle { get; set; }
    public String SessionDesc { get; set; }
    public Guid ClassId { get; set; }
    public String ClassName { get; set; }
    public Guid TeacherId { get; set; }
    public String TeacherName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ScheduledDate { set; get; }
    public String StartingTime { get; set; }
    public String EndingTime { get; set; }
    public Guid? SessionStatusId { get; set; }

    public String SessionStatus { get; set; }
  }
}
```

and mapped as

```
CreateMap<SessionDetail, SessionViewModel>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.TeacherName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Teacher.Name))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.ClassName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ClassDetail.ClassName));
```

While fetching all the session data in controller, I am getting Teacher and Class object null, and not able to get values in ClassName and TeacherName. This is the code in controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllSection([FromQuery] BaseParameter baseParameter)
        {
            var results = await _sessionService.ListAsync(baseParameter);
            var resultViewModel = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SessionDetail>, IEnumerable<SessionViewModel>>(results);
            var metadata = new
            {
                results.TotalCount,
                results.PageSize,
                results.CurrentPage,
                results.TotalPages,
                results.HasNext,
                results.HasPrevious
            };

            Response.Headers.Add("X-Pagination", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(metadata));

            return Ok(resultViewModel);
        }
```

In resultViewModel ClassName and TeacherName is null.
As ClassDetail and Teacher object is null in result itself.

ListAsync Method in SessionService

```
 public async Task<PagedList<SessionDetail>> ListAsync(BaseParameter baseParameter)
        {
            return await _sessionRepository.GetPaginatedList(baseParameter);
        }
```

And in Repository

```
public async Task<PagedList<TModel>> GetPaginatedList(BaseParameter baseParameter)
    {
      var result = await entities.Where(x => x.Active == ActiveStatus.Active.ToString()).ToListAsync();
      return PagedList<TModel>.ToPagedList(result, baseParameter.PageNumber, baseParameter.PageSize);
    }
```

PagedList.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace OnlineLearning.DTO.Queries
{
    public class PagedList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public int CurrentPage { get; private set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; private set; }
        public int PageSize { get; private set; }
        public int TotalCount { get; private set; }

        public bool HasPrevious => CurrentPage > 1;
        public bool HasNext => CurrentPage < TotalPages;

        public PagedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            TotalCount = count;
            PageSize = pageSize;
            CurrentPage = pageNumber;
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

            AddRange(items);
        }

        public static PagedList<T> ToPagedList(IEnumerable<T> source, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            var count = source.Count();
            var items = source.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();

            return new PagedList<T>(items, count, pageNumber, pageSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When `results` does not return the `ClassDetail``and `Teacher` objects then AutoMapper will not have them as well. Please [edit] your question to include the source code of the `ListAsync()` method. Actually, please provide a [mcve] which can be tested by others. Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: You are not using `Include(it => it.NavProp)` to load the content of navigation properties as well when you loading the `SessionDetail` entities. Is there a reason for that? Or is there a different place somewhere where you load the navigation properties of your entities?